# Framer-Motion: Is there a way to have a custom dom type

Tags: reactjs, optimization, framer-motion

I'm trying to optimize the bundle size for my React website and I am currently working through framer-motion lazy motion to reduce the overall size. A spring animation breaks when I use domAinimation but works as intended if I utilize maxDom. Is it possible to create a custom type that, say, extends domAnimation and adds the barest features required to make spring animation work?

I have tried looking on framer-motion documentation (located here https://www.framer.com/motion/lazy-motion/ ) for a possible solution and came up empty-handed, hence my question.